# For which ${n \in \mathbb{Z}^+_0}$ is the number ${2^n - 1}$ divisible by 7?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

This is how far I've gotten:

Let ${n=3k+r}$, where ${r=0,1}$ or $2$ (since ${0 \le r < 3}$).

Case ${r=0}$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
2^{3k} &\equiv_7 1\\
\Rightarrow 2^{3k}-1 &\equiv_7 0\\
k &\in \mathbb{Z}^+_0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

For cases ${r=1}$ and ${r=2}$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
2^{3k+r}-1 &\equiv_7 0\\
\Leftrightarrow 2^{3k} \cdot 2^r -1 &\equiv_7 0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which gives

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
2^0-1=0 &\equiv_7 0\\
2^1-1=1 &\equiv_7 1\\
2^2-1=3 &\equiv_7 3\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I know (by more or less messing around) that ${r=0,3}$ or $6$ for ${k \in \mathbb{Z}^+_0}$, but I'm getting nowhere in trying to prove it. And I'm not sure how $r$ actually can be 3 or 6 since $r$ should be smaller than 3. Right?

Any hints or guidings towards the right answer would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth noting $2^{3k+r}\equiv 2^{3k}2^r \equiv (2^3)^k2^r\equiv 8^k2^r\equiv 1^k2^r\equiv 2^r$.  So you only need to consider cases $r=0,1,2$ and $2^0\equiv 1$ and $2^1\equiv 2\not \equiv 1$ and $2^2 \equiv 4\not \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Comment: "And I'm not sure how r actually can be 3 or 6 since r should be smaller than 3. Right?"  Okay... we need to state the division theorem.  For any $q\in \mathbb N$ and any integer $n$ there exist a unique set of integer $d$ and $r$ with $r: 0 \le r < q$ so that $n = qd +r$.  So we are just applying that with $q=3$.  For any integer $n$ the exists a unique integer $k$ and a unique $r = 0,1$ or $2$ so that $n = 3k + r$....(Note: $k$ is negative if and only if $n$ is negative.  If $n$ is natural (or $0$) then $k$ non-negative)

Comment: @fleablood Thank you! I smacked my head straight away. I'm a bit too tired, I guess! Thank you!

Comment: If you have $r = 3$ or $6$ so $27 = 3\times 7 + 6$ just do $27 = 3\times (7 + 2) + 0 = 3\times 9 + 0$.

Comment: We all been there.  It gets frustrating how to generalize what is pretty obvious but we aren't sure we are allowed to say..."well, it's obvious..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind if $a \equiv 1$ then $a\times k \equiv 1 \times k \equiv k$ and $a^m \equiv 1^m \equiv 1$.

So as you have figured we can writ any $n$ as $n = 3k + r$ where $r=0,1$ or $2$ and $k$ can be any natural number.

And we figure $2^3 \equiv 8 \equiv 1$ so........

$2^{3k+r}= 2^{3k}\times 2^r =(2^3)^k\times 2^r = 8^k \times 2^r \equiv 1^k\times 2^r \equiv 2^r \pmod 7$.  Always.

And from that we can conclude that for *all* natural numbers we have one of the following $3$ cases:

1. If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ that is if there is a $k$ so $n = 3k + 0$ then

$2^{n} \equiv 2^0\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.  And our case is always satisfied.

2. If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ that is if there is a $k$ so $n = 3k + 1$ then

$2^n \equiv 2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$. And our case is never satisfied (but we we *always* have $n \equiv 1\pmod 7 \implies 2^n\equiv 2 \pmod 7$.)

3. If $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ that is if there is a $k$ so $n = 3k + 2$ then

$2^n \equiv 2^2 \equiv 4\pmod 7$. And our case is never satisfied (be we *always* have $n\equiv 2\pmod 7\implies 2^n\equiv 4\pmod 7$. Always.)

So that's that.

if $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $2^n \equiv 1\pmod 7$.  Always.  And if $n \not \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $2^n \not \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.  Never.

Answer (score 1):

Since $2^3\equiv1\pmod7$, you have that, when $3\mid n$, $2^n\equiv1\pmod7$.

On the other hand, if $3\nmid n$, you can write $n$ as $3k+1$ or as $3k+2$, for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. Then $2^n\equiv2\pmod7$ or $2^n\equiv2^2\pmod7$. But $2\not\equiv1\pmod7$ and $2^2\not\equiv1\pmod7$. So, the answer is: $\{n\in\Bbb Z\mid3\mid n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, is to note : $$7=2^3-1$$ and $$2^{m+1}-1=2(2^m-1)+(2^1-1)$$ iterating this tells you :
$$2^m-1\mid 2^n-1\implies m\mid n$$ which tells you the exponent must be divisible by $3$ for $7$ to divide it.